# Tomcat server startup on netbeans 7.0.1

Tags: apache, tomcat, netbeans, catalina

I've installed a tomcat server in netbeans but when I try to start the server I get this list of errors!

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat6
>   Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat6
>   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat6/temp
>   Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
>   Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar
>   java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat6/logs/catalina.2015-06-06.log (No such file or directory)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:210)
>       at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:374)
>       at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.(FileHandler.java:99)
>       at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.(FileHandler.java:90)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
>       at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:529)
>       at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:474)
>       at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:300)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:294)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:292)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:292)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:275)
>       at java.util.logging.Logger.(Logger.java:254)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.(LogManager.java:1327)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.(LogManager.java:1325)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:196)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager.(LogManager.java:173)
>       at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:328)
>       at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:369)
>       at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
>       at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:178)
>       at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:171)
>       at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:243)
>       at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:298)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.(Bootstrap.java:55)
>   java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat6/logs/localhost.2015-06-06.log (No such file or directory)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:210)
>       at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:374)
>       at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.(FileHandler.java:99)
>       at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.(FileHandler.java:90)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
>       at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:529)
>       at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:474)
>       at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:300)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:294)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:292)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:292)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:275)
>       at java.util.logging.Logger.(Logger.java:254)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.(LogManager.java:1327)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.(LogManager.java:1325)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:196)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.util.logging.LogManager.(LogManager.java:173)
>       at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:328)
>       at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:369)
>       at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
>       at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:178)
>       at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:171)
>       at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:243)
>       at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:298)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.(Bootstrap.java:55)
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.14 org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
>   AVVERTENZA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.14 org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
>   AVVERTENZA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.14 org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
>   AVVERTENZA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.14 org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
>   AVVERTENZA: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.14 org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded initDirs
>   GRAVE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at /usr/share/tomcat6/temp
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.16 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
>   INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.16 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>   INFO: Initialization processed in 1521 ms
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.16 org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
>   AVVERTENZA: Unexpected exception resolving reference
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/tomcat-users.xml (Permission denied)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.open(MemoryUserDatabase.java:386)
>       at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.getObjectInstance(MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.java:103)
>       at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:140)
>       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:793)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:113)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:71)
>       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:137)
>       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:81)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:747)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.16 org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener createMBeans
>   GRAVE: Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
>   javax.naming.NamingException: /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/tomcat-users.xml (Permission denied)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:805)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:113)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:71)
>       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:137)
>       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:81)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:747)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.16 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
>   INFO: Starting service Catalina
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.16 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
>   INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.39
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.16 org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
>   AVVERTENZA: Unexpected exception resolving reference
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/tomcat-users.xml (Permission denied)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.open(MemoryUserDatabase.java:386)
>       at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.getObjectInstance(MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.java:103)
>       at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:140)
>       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:793)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
>       at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.start(UserDatabaseRealm.java:253)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1049)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.16 org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm start
>   GRAVE: Exception looking up UserDatabase under key UserDatabase
>   javax.naming.NamingException: /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/tomcat-users.xml (Permission denied)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:805)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
>       at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.start(UserDatabaseRealm.java:253)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1049)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.16 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   GRAVE: Catalina.start: 
>   LifecycleException:  No UserDatabase component found under key UserDatabase
>       at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.start(UserDatabaseRealm.java:261)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1049)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   6-giu-2015 13.47.16 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   INFO: Server startup in 47 ms

where could the problem be?? and what's the problem anyway?

Comment: check out is there any `dir` exists named `/usr/share/tomcat6/logs/`

Comment: No, it doesn't exist

Comment: see the Error, what does it say.
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat6/logs/catalina.2015-06-06.log (No such file or directory)`
I think it is a Problem with your **DIR** it cant find it. Make a Dir under **/usr/share/tomcat6/logs/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JRE_HOME is missing a `/` at the start of it.

Your **CATALINA_HOME** and **CLASSPATH** also looks wrong, with a local.tomcat instead of a `local/tomcat` and `c\tomcat-juli` instead of `tomcat-juli`